# How to run selenium tests without the need to launch web app first

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have an MVC web application in development. 
Currently to run my Selenium browser tests I have to right click on one of the views and choose "View In Browser". This initiates the web application and then I can run my browser tests.

Is there a way I can effectively "launch" the website as part of the setup() and teardown() of the test?

e.g.

```
 [TestFixture]
 public class MainNavigationTests
 {
    // here I have to predetermine the localhost port that Visual Studio uses
    const string host = "http://localhost:57237/";
    IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    [Test]
    public void canBrowseToHomePage()
    {
        driver.Url = host;
        Assert.AreEqual("Index - My web app", driver.Title);
        var homePageLink = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("navbar-brand"));
        homePageLink.Click();
        Assert.IsTrue(driver.PageSource.Contains("The home page of the web app"));
    }    
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What you're suggesting is exactly what it sounds like you should be doing, have you tried putting it in the setup method? and if so what's the behavior or what errors are you seeing?

Comment: yeah :) i have no idea how to write the code to automate the "right click, view in web browser" type action... and obviously then i have no error, since I don't know where to start! hehe. i thought i could publish to our dev environment and browser test on that, but that would defeat the purpose of testing before publishing right? i'd much rather do this on localhost on my own machine first.

Comment: maybe i misunderstood the question but my suggestion is that you have a OneTimeSetup method that instantiates your driver and opens up the browser then you could have a Setup method that maybe always goes to your home page so that each of your tests always has the same starting point

Comment: my problem is that the site at http://localhost:57237/ doesn't exist until I take some manual action in Visual Studio. Until I manually instantiate the host and web-site by clicking around in visual studio, all my tests time out (the site can't be found) It looks like I'm stuck with this for now. thanks for the help and effort, all the same - at least now it looks like what i was trying to do isn't possible. i can move on!

Comment: Just a thought.. you could write a powershell script to deploy the site then within your setup method call that script

Comment: Ok - could go with something like that. I do eventually want to put these steps into a CI build, so I'm hoping for something that won't get in the way there too... haha! I'm demanding! Thanks again.